# ASP.NET MVC Model Errors keep displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I have some validation on my code where I enter my address, city, phone number etc. This function works perfectly fine and returns errors as needed. When I switch from one view to another and then back on a side bar I have, the validation errors are still there. I'd like to clear these values so that I dont see them everytime I go back to the tab.
I've tried

```
modelstate.clear()
```

and that doesnt work, so any other ideas would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify the phrase "When I switch from one view to another and then back on a side bar I have, the validation errors are still there."

Comment: How are you displaying these validation errors?

Comment: @MattRazza
@Html.ValidationSummary(false) is how i display my errors

Comment: @TravisJ
@{ Html.RenderPartial("SideNav", new ViewDataDictionary { { "name", "reload" } });  }  

Using that I have a side navigation bar to redirect me to where id like to go

Comment: @user2094139 - We really are going to need a significant amount of data here to help you. Consider this, with the given information on this page, would you be able to answer this question? At the moment we can only guess. My best guess would be that you are using ajax to load content and the jquery-validate front end is still in its previous state. Another guess would be that the errors which were added to the page are never removed once a partial is loaded and they are simply hidden temporarily. But, these are just guesses, which is why no one has answered. Help us help you.

Comment: Nice Jerry Maguire reference my man!!! @TravisJ (It is the movie phrase right :D)

Comment: LOL @TravisJ thanks for your input. I took a deeper look at the code and I found the problem. I still had the session stored so it kept outputting model errors. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session.Clear() fixed my problem.